# How do I properly use arguments in baseballr

Tags: r

Basballr gives me fits and would like some help for someone who actually uses this package.  I am using the mlb_game_pks( date, level), and it is very picky with the Invalid arguments error. Below you will find what I tried, and I am totally befuddled.

```
> z1_update <- mlb_game_pks( (date = dates_to_process_c[1] ), level_ids = c(1))
2023-09-08 12:34:08: Invalid arguments provided
> z1_update <- mlb_game_pks( dates_to_process_c[1] , level_ids = c(1))
2023-09-08 12:35:27: Invalid arguments provided
> z1_update <- mlb_game_pks( as.Date(dates_to_process_c[1] ), level_ids = c(1))
2023-09-08 12:35:52: Invalid arguments provided
> z1_update <- mlb_game_pks( as.Date(dates_to_process_c[1], format = "%y-%m-%d" ), level_ids = c(1))
2023-09-08 12:36:24: Invalid arguments provided
> class(dates_to_process_c[1])
[1] "Date"
> dates_to_process_c[1]
[1] "2023-07-10"
```

Comment: There were no [games played on July 10th, 2023](https://www.mlb.com/scores/2023-07-10). Test with a date with 1+ games and update if you still have an error. Example: `mlb_game_pks("2023-07-11")`

Comment: Damn, I am so stupid.  That was the all-star break.  My bad.  Thanks for your help